# How do I properly train and predict value like biomass using GRU RNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, gradient-descent

My first time trying to train a dataset containing 8 variables in a time-series of 20 years or so using GRU RNN. The biomass value is what I'm trying to predict based on the other variables. I'm trying first with 1 layer GRU. I'm not using softmax for the output layer. MSE is used for my cost function.

It is basic GRU with forward propagation and backward gradient update. Here are the main function I defined:

```py
   'x_t is the input training dataset with a dimension of 7572x8. So T = 7572, input_dim = 8, hidden_dim =128. y_train is my train label.'

   def forward_prop_step(self, x_t,y_train, s_t1_prev,V, U, W, b, c,learning_rate):
       T = x_t.shape[0]
       z_t1 = np.zeros((T,self.hidden_dim))
       r_t1 = np.zeros((T,self.hidden_dim))
       h_t1 = np.zeros((T,self.hidden_dim))
       s_t1 = np.zeros((T+1,self.hidden_dim))
       o_s = np.zeros((T,self.input_dim))
       for i in xrange(T):
           x_e = x_t[i].T
           z_t1[i] = sigmoid(U[0].dot(x_e) + W[0].dot(s_t1[i]) + b[0])#128x1
           r_t1[i] = sigmoid(U[1].dot(x_e) + W[1].dot(s_t1[i]) + b[1])#128x1
           h_t1[i] = np.tanh(U[2].dot(x_e) + W[2].dot(s_t1[i] * r_t1[i]) + b[2])#128x1
           s_t1[i+1] = (np.ones_like(z_t1[i]) - z_t1[i]) * h_t1[i] + z_t1[i] * s_t1[i]#128x1

           o_s[i] = np.dot(V,s_t1[i+1]) + c#8x1
       return [o_s,z_t1,r_t1,h_t1,s_t1]

   def bptt(self, x,y_train,o,z_t1,r_t1,h_t1,s_t1,V, U, W, b, c):
       bptt_truncate = 360
       T = x.shape[0]#length of time scale of input data (train)
       dLdU = np.zeros(U.shape)
       dLdV = np.zeros(V.shape)
       dLdW = np.zeros(W.shape)
       dLdb = np.zeros(b.shape)
       dLdc = np.zeros(c.shape)
       y_train_sp = np.repeat(y_train,self.input_dim)
       for t in np.arange(T)[::-1]:
           dLdy = 2 * (o[t] - y_train_sp[t])
           dydV = s_t1[t]
           dydc = 1.0
           dLdV += np.outer(dLdy,dydV)
           dLdc += dLdy*dydc            
           for i in np.arange(max(0, t-bptt_truncate), t+1)[::-30]:#every month in the past year           
               s_t1_pre = s_t1[i]          
               dydst1 = V #8x128                
               dst1dzt1 = -h_t1[i] + s_t1_pre #128x1
               dst1dht1 = np.ones_like(z_t1[i]) - z_t1[i] #128x1

               dzt1dU = np.outer(z_t1[i]*(1.0-z_t1[i]),x[i]) #128x8
               #print dzt1dU.shape
               dzt1dW = np.outer(z_t1[i]*(1.0-z_t1[i]),s_t1_pre)  #128x128
               dzt1db = z_t1[i]*(1.0-z_t1[i]) #128x1

               dht1dU = np.outer((1.0-h_t1[i] ** 2),x[i]) #128x8
               dht1dW = np.outer((1.0-h_t1[i] ** 2),s_t1_pre * r_t1[i])  #128x128
               dht1db = 1.0-h_t1[i] ** 2 #128x1

               dht1drt1 = (1.0-h_t1[i] ** 2)*(W[2].dot(s_t1_pre))#128x1

               drt1dU = np.outer((r_t1[i]*(1.0-r_t1[i])),x[i]) #128x8
               drt1dW = np.outer((r_t1[i]*(1.0-r_t1[i])),s_t1_pre) #128x128
               drt1db = (r_t1[i]*(1.0-r_t1[i]))#128x1
               dLdW[0] += np.outer(dydst1.T.dot(dLdy),dzt1dW.dot(dst1dzt1)) #128x128
               dLdU[0] += np.outer(dydst1.T.dot(dLdy),dst1dzt1.dot(dzt1dU)) #128x8
               dLdb[0] += (dydst1.T.dot(dLdy))*dst1dzt1*dzt1db#128x1

               dLdW[1] += np.outer(dydst1.T.dot(dLdy),dst1dht1*dht1drt1).dot(drt1dW)#128x128
               dLdU[1] += np.outer(dydst1.T.dot(dLdy),dst1dht1*dht1drt1).dot(drt1dU) #128x8
               dLdb[1] += (dydst1.T.dot(dLdy))*dst1dht1*dht1drt1*drt1db#128x1

               dLdW[2] += np.outer(dydst1.T.dot(dLdy),dht1dW.dot(dst1dht1))  #128x128
               dLdU[2] += np.outer(dydst1.T.dot(dLdy),dst1dht1.dot(dht1dU))#128x8
               dLdb[2] += (dydst1.T.dot(dLdy))*dst1dht1*dht1db#128x1

       return [ dLdV,dLdU, dLdW, dLdb, dLdc ]
   def predict( self, x): 
       pred = np.amax(x, axis = 1)
       pred_f = relu(pred)
       return pred_f
```

Parameters *V*,*U*,*W*,*b*,*c* are updated by gradient *dLdV*,*dLdU*,*dLdW*,*dLdb*,*dLdc* calculated by *bptt*.

I have tried different weight initialization (xavier or just random), tried different time truncation. But all lead to the same outcome. Probably the weight update wasn't right? The network set-up seems simple though. Really struggle on understanding the predication and translate to actual biomass too. The function *predict* is what I defined to translate the output layer from the GRU network to biomass value by taking the maximum value. But the output layer gives similar value for almost all time iterations. Not sure the best way to do the job though. Thanks for any help or suggestions in advance.

Comment: Seconding @olooney. Why are you writing code from scratch instead of using a Keras RNN / LSTM implementation? Is there a reason you're writing your own code from scratch?

Comment: Thanks @ias I always first try to implement from scratch so I can fully understand what is going on. Apparently sometime it is frustrating. Will try more on the built ones.

Comment: Consider the programming assignments in the [Coursera Deeplearning.ai Sequence Models](https://www.coursera.org/learn/nlp-sequence-models/home/welcome) course. The first assignment contains does what you're trying to do and contains test cases to check your code. Auditing the course is free.

Comment: Auditing now. Thanks @ias !

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anyone on stackoverflow is going to debug a custom implementation of GRU for you. If you were using Tensorflow or another high level library, I might take a stab at it, or if it was a simple fully connected network, but as it is all I can do is give some advice on how to proceed with debugging.

First, it sounds like you're running a brand new implementation on your own data set right off the bat. Instead, try starting out by testing your network on trivial, synthetic data sets first. Can it learn an identity function? A response which is simply the weighted average of the three previous time stamps? And so on. It's easier to debug small simple problems. Once you know your implementation can learn things that a GRU based recurrent network should be able to learn, then you can start using your own data.

Second, this comment of yours was very insightful:

> Probably the weight update wasn't right?

While it's impossible to say for sure, this is a very common - perhaps *the* most common - source of bugs in for backprop implementations. Andrew Ng recommends [gradient checking](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/machine-learning/gradient-checking-Y3s6r) to debug an implementation like this. Essentially, this involves numerically approximating the gradient. It's computationally inefficient but relies only on a correct implementation of forward propagation, which makes it very useful for debugging. For one, if the algorithm converges when the numerically approximated gradient is used, you can be more sure that your forward prop is correct and focus on debugging backprop. (On the other hand, if it is still does not succeed, it is likely the issue in your forward prop function.) For another, once the algorithm is working with the numerically approximated gradient then you can compare the output of your analytic gradient function with it and debug any discrepancies. This makes it a lot easier because you now know the correct answer that it *should* return.

Comment: Thanks @olooney I played with Theano a bit today, but having issues with the scan function for weight update. Will try more. Nevertheless, how to translate the last output layer o_s (with dimension 8x1) to a single biomass value (1) is still not clear to me after reviewing many online articles. Taking the max seems the popular way for classification, but not sure for the actual value prediction.